# how to convert char to number in matlab?

Tags: matlab, char, numbers

Please help me with the following problem:

In matlab, I have an Nx3 char variable, where N can vary depending on the input. 
Let's say N = 5 and I have the following variable A (5x3 char):

```
A = [' 1Y';
     ' 5Y';
     '10Y';
     '15Y';
     '20Y']
```

Is there a way to define a new variable B having as values the numbers in variable A, i.e. `B=[1; 5; 10; 15; 20]`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Voted to reopen as this problem appears to be slightly different, and also the solution to the supposed duplicate will not work here. (Because this contains multicharacter numbers)

Comment: Put here because question is closed: If your variable looks like this `A = ' 1Y 5Y10Y15Y20Y'` You are probably happy with something like: `C=strsplit(A,'Y'), V=cellfun(@str2num,C)`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - You're right. Reopening.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - BTW, `strsplit` won't work here because this is an array of characters, not a single string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @DennisJaheruddin! The problem is that the variable A is a 5by3 char, so when doing C=strsplit(A,'Y'), I get the following error: The 'STRING' input must be a one-dimensional array of char or cell arrays of strings. Any ideas how to deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng I tried with strsplit and didn't work, any suggestions how to go about this problem?

Comment: @Astrid - See my answer.

Comment: @Astrid With your comments we managed to figure it out, but in general you will want to give actual examples of your input (or the code to create them) and desired outputs. In this case your output was good, but the input was not something you can just paste into Matlab, which makes it a bit harder to know what you need.

Comment: @rayryeng I have posted the new question under the title 'convert different chars to number in matlab'. I also included some code that I tried and didn't work. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your input is a character array, first convert each row into a cell to allow use with the string functions in MATLAB:

```
out = mat2cell(val, ones(size(val,1),1));
```

[`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) converts a matrix into a series of cells.  In our case, you would like to have 5 cells, or as many cells as there are rows in your matrix `val` and each cell will be as long as the total number of column in `val`.

Once you do this, you can replace the `Y` strings with nothing, then convert to numbers:

```
out = strrep(out, 'Y', '');
out2 = cellfun(@str2num, out);
```

The first line uses [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to replace any instances of `Y` with nothing, and then we apply [`str2num`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) on each of the cells to convert the trimmed string into an actual number.  This is through the use of [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) so that we can iterate through each cell apply `str2num` to each cell.

We get:

```
out2 =

     1
     5
    10
    15
    20
```

---

To be fully reproducible:

```
val = ['1Y '; '5Y '; '10Y'; '15Y'; '20Y'];
out = mat2cell(val, ones(size(val,1),1), size(val,2));
out = strrep(out, 'Y', '');
out2 = cellfun(@str2num, out);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rayryeng! It worked! Could you please help me with the following problem: What if instead A=1M, 5D, 10Y, 15W, 20Y, i.e. different time values and I would like to transform everything in years, to have: B=[1/12, 5/365, 10, 15/52, 20], with numbers only, no letters. Thanks again!

Comment: @Astrid - My pleasure!  That's actually a completely different problem.  I'd like to ask you to open up a new question that asks this.  in the mean time, I'll come up with some code.

Comment: @Astrid Indeed a separate question, to help you ask that properly the following tips: 1. Specify exactly what you need (Only DWMY or should it somehow work with microseconds as well?; Will it always be exactly three characters?) 2. Show what you have tried so far and let people know where you get stuck. -- It is easy to ask here, but it should always be clear that you ask here after you failed to solve it and already tried to find a solution for it yourself.

Comment: @rayryeng I will post the question as soon as it will be possible (there is a time restriction)

Comment: @rayryeng Just a detail, but the call to `mat2cell` can be made slightly less intimidating by eliminating the third input argument.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin thank you for your tips, I will take them into consideration.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - yes that's right. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have the following:

```
A = [' 1Y';
' 5Y';
'10Y';
'15Y';
'20Y';]
```

Then this should do the trick:

```
B=A'
C=strsplit(B(:)','Y')
V=cellfun(@str2num,C(1:end-1))
```

Comment: @dennis I tried this and I get as a result that C is 1by6 instead of 1by5, I have an empty value as last value. So also V is going to be 1by6.

Comment: @astrid updated answer, perhaps the accepted answer is more elegant now

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can convert a `cellstr` to its numeric value:

```
a = {'1'};
ans1 = int64(str2num(a{1}));
```