# convert different chars to number in matlab

Tags: matlab, char, numbers

```
Please help me with the following problem:

In matlab, I have an Nx3 char variable, where N can vary depending on the input. Let's say N = 5 and I have the following variable A (5x3 char):

A = [' 1M';
     ' 5D';
     '10Y';
     '15W';
     '20Y']
```

A is always Nx3, and can take only 'D', 'W', 'M', 'Y', so no microseconds.
Is there a way to define a new variable B having as values the numbers in variable A, expressed in years, i.e. B=[1/12; 5/365; 10; 15/52; 20]?

What I tried so far and didn't work (example for M):

```
outc = mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1),1), size(A,2));
for k = 1:length(outc) 
    if  outc{k} = '\w*M' 
        outc{k} = strrep(outc, 'M', '');
        outc2(k) = cellfun(@str2num, outc);
        outc2(k) = outc2(k)./12;
    end
end

Thank you for your help!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is set up a lookup table that maps characters to numbers.  In your case, you'd have a lookup table that maps `'D'` to 365, `'W'` to 52, `'M'` to 12 and `'Y`' to 1.  You can easily do that with a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html).  Specifically, you would to this to set it up:

```
map = containers.Map({'D', 'W', 'M', 'Y'}, {365, 52, 12, 1});
```

This maps each of the characters to each number that we talked about.  Next, [referencing your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880545/how-to-convert-char-to-number-in-matlab/31881052#31881052), you'd convert each row of your character matrix to a cell array.  However, I would also [trim out any whitespace via `strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) so that our analysis is easier:

```
B = mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1),1));
B = strtrim(B); %// Trim out whitespace
```

Now, all you have to do is go through each cell, convert all of the characters **before** the last one into a number, then use the last character and reference our lookup table to spit out the right number:

```
out = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x(1:end-1)) / map(x(end)), B);
```

We get:

```
out =

    0.0833
    0.0137
   10.0000
    0.2885
   20.0000
```

Compare this with the actual numbers in fractional form before converting to floating point:

```
>> out2 = [1/12, 5/365, 10, 15/52, 20]

out2 =

    0.0833    0.0137   10.0000    0.2885   20.0000
```

Looks good to me!

---

For copying and pasting:

```
A = [' 1M';
     ' 5D';
     '10Y';
     '15W';
     '20Y'];
map = containers.Map({'D', 'W', 'M', 'Y'}, {365, 52, 12, 1});
B = mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1),1));
B = strtrim(B); %// Trim out whitespace
out = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x(1:end-1)) / map(x(end)), B);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer: very elegant and beautifully explained!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach similar to [@rayryeng's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31882726/2586922), but using a regular expression ([`regexprep`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html)) instead of a map:

```
B = mat2cell(A, ones(size(A,1),1)); %// convert each line to a cell
B = regexprep(B, {'Y' 'M' 'W' 'D' }, {'' '/12' '/52' '/365'}); %// replace letters
B = cellfun(@str2num, B); %// convert from strings to numbers
```

For

```
A = [' 1M';
     ' 5D';
     '10Y';
     '15W';
     '20Y'];
```

this gives

```
B =
    0.0833
    0.0137
   10.0000
    0.2885
   20.0000
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW I borrowed (literally copied) your `mat2cell` line :-D

Comment: Hahaha no problem at all :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you very much for your answer, I also tried to use regexp, but now the approach is clear!